# FLASHBACK feature in ORACLE 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g r1. as a part of project i have to execute multiple update statements by disabling few constraints(Triggers and Check constraints). Which will result a corrupted database.

when the database got corrupted i have to re import entire database. which will be an additional task which is time consuming.

I have very little knowledge about oracle flashback feature. Is Flashback will help me to avoid these unnecessary imports. So that i can set some stable point and switch back to there when anything goes wrong.

if it fits for my requirement i will try to learn. Please help me.

Please give me brief overview on this feature ?

Comment: Brief overview: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm

Comment: You shouldn't disable the constraints in the first place. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in My project i am using the existing scripts. They followed the approach where they disabled all the constraints. I should follow them.(Atleast to meet the deadline)

Comment: You should really re-consider that approach. Using deferrable constraints as Justin suggested is probably a much better solution (and will probably quicker to implement than a flashback solution - which comes with additional licensing costs!)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name with my current experience of 1+ year, i cant suggest an alternative approch :), Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are hoping to [create a restore point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/rpfbdb002.htm), most likely a guaranteed restore point, implement whatever changes you want to test, and then [flashback to that restore point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/flashdb.htm#CFHCEIHB).

Something like

```
CREATE RESTORE POINT some_name GUARANTEE FLASHBACK DATABASE;
```

Then make whatever changes you want.  If you want to get back to the state of the database at the point you created the restore point

```
FLASHBACK DATABASE TO RESTORE POINT 'some_name'
```

When you're done with the restore point and no longer want to be able to flashback to it

```
DROP RESTORE POINT some_name
```

It's not actually clear, though, whether that is really what you want.  If your problem is simply that your constraints fail to validate after you've made a bunch of changes, it would make much more sense to create the constraints as deferrable, defer the constraints before making your changes, make your changes as part of a single transaction, and rollback the changes if the constraints fail to verify (possibly in addition to logging the rows that fail to validate so that you can debug your script more effectively).

Comment: Another alternative (to deferrable constraints) might be to log the offending rows using the "log errors into" option when doing the updates/inserts